# How to apply Grails 3 interceptors to Spring Boot Actuator endpoints

Tags: grails, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am attempting to apply a Grails 3.0.12 interceptor with a uri matcher to the management endpoints provided by Spring Boot Actuator. I have the actuator ***management.context_path*** property set to **/admin**.

All endpoints mapped in UrlMappings.groovy are being intercepted but those [managed by Spring Boot Actuator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints) are not. I instead see the following in the logs indicating that the interceptor is being bypassed:

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /admin/metrics
DEBUG: org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()]
```

Here is my interceptor:

```
class LoginInterceptor {

    def securityService

    int order = HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE

    LoginInterceptor() {
        match(uri: "/**")
    }

    boolean before() {
        if (!request.exception) {
            securityService.authenticateUser()
        }
        true
    }

    boolean after() { true }

    void afterView() { /* no-op */ }
}
```

Here is the management config in application.yml

```
management:
  context_path: /admin
```

How do I ensure that actuator-provided endpoints are intercepted?

Answer (score 0):

I did find one way of doing this by implementing the EndpointHandlerMappingCustomizer customize() method where the GrailsInterceptorHandlerInterceptorAdapter is set as an interceptor.

```
import org.grails.plugins.web.interceptors.GrailsInterceptorHandlerInterceptorAdapter
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointHandlerMappingCustomizer

class ActuatorInterceptor implements EndpointHandlerMappingCustomizer {
    GrailsInterceptorHandlerInterceptorAdapter interceptorAdapter

    @Override
    public void customize(EndpointHandlerMapping mapping) {
        Object[] interceptors = [ interceptorAdapter ]
        mapping.setInterceptors(interceptors)
    }
}
```

resources.groovy:

```
beans = {
    actuatorInterceptor(ActuatorInterceptor) {
        interceptorAdapter = ref('grailsInterceptorHandlerInterceptorAdapter')
    }
}
```

This is less than ideal since it's specific to Spring Boot Actuator and won't work for, say, Spring Cloud Config endpoints. I would like to see a more generalized way to intercept all URI mappings *with a Grails interceptor*.